# Stop screen saver from waking up?

Tags: lockscreen, screensaver

Is it possible to start a screen saver and stop the screen saver from waking up when the mouse moves or when when keys are pressed?

I want to be able to display an emergency warning full screen message on the computer (like during a fire evacuation) and so I want to lock the computer remotely, change the screen saver to a screen saver that has the message I want to display and start the screen saver when the screen is locked. I have done some research and I think I might be able to do all that but I want to make sure the message says up. I could probably have a loop and keep restarting the screen saver but if there is a way to limit what input can wake the screen saver I think that would be better.

I will only be running this on Windows 7 computers.

Comment: An alternative for screen save is sing something as simple as Autohotkey. A combination of SplashImage and BlockInput will do what you want.

Comment: Still haven't quiet figured this out, but I am trying a different method now.
I should be able to launch IE in kiosk mode IExplorer.exe -k "http://warning.html" that will work for what I want. But still trying to get it to display of the lock screen. Supposable launching with PSExec.exe -s -i 0 "IExplorer.exe" -k "http://warning.html" should work but I havn't had got it working yet.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot on this, but didn't found any suggestions. Maybe you can try it from another perspective:

Use [Toddler Keys](http://download.cnet.com/Toddler-Keys/3000-27064_4-10305344.html) (with you can disable your keyboard/mouse), and use macros on it. So whenever you want to make this alarm, run a macro file on each computers that opens Toddler Keys, turns off keyboard and mouse, and runs the screen saver as a warning message. After it run another macro that kills Toddler Keys from processes.

Hope that helps